# Enable MERGEABLE_LIBRARY in Kotlin Multiplatform for mobile for iOS dynamic framework

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, xcode15

In order to take advantage of [mergeable binaries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-your-project-to-use-mergeable-libraries) as introduced in Xcode 15, how we can enable it in the dynamic framework generated from KMM for use in IOS ? Enabling build setting MERGEABLE_LIBRARY to YES will make the framework mergeable. Can anyone suggest a way to do it inside relevant build.gradle.kts?

Comment: Why it is given -1? What's wrong with the question?